# NestJs Segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, nestjs, prisma

I have a segmentation fault randomly happening when working on my nestjs project, the segmentation comes once in a while, there is day where the segmentation fault comes and days where the seg fault does not shows up, however I think the error is related to Prisma, as it seems that the seg fault occurs when I try to manipulate the database with nestjs through Prisma.

Here are the log of nestjs app

```
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] BcryptModule dependencies initialized +13ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] PrismaModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] LibModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtTokenModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TwoFaModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] UserModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/auth}: +12ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/signup, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/login, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/oauth_callback, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/refresh, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] UserController {/user}: +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/user/me, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] TwoFaController {/auth/2fa}: +1ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/2fa/generate, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 27627  - 09/29/2023, 12:00:04 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/2fa/validate-otp, POST} route +0ms
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I also faced the same issue when I upgraded the node version to 18.x.x from 16.x.x.